# Missing .NETCore v4.5.1

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I have Windows 8.1 Home machine with Visual Studio Express 2013 Update 2 and Windows 8.1 SDK installed. I am trying to build an application against .NETCore 4.5.1 libraries, but I'm getting lot of compiler errors just like this:

```
error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5.1\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll' could not be found
```

The reason is that in c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\ there is only v4.5 directory.

I've tried to install .NET Framework 4.5.1 and update my Visual Studio to the newest version. I've also tried to google where I can get this specific (or any) version of .NETCore but with no luck.

On my friend's machine this directory exists, but we cannot tell what he have installed to get it in the first place.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like the Runtime installer should do it, from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vstudio/hh487283.aspx - any luck? there's also the developer pack: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40772

Comment: There are two Express editions, "for Windows" and "for Desktop".  Non-zero odds that you got the wrong one, .NETCore is normally only required for Store and Phone apps.  The "for Windows" version.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. @MarcGravell I've tried both, I and believe I've installed these before. The installers told me the same (cannot install because it is already installed).

Comment: @HansPassant I've got VSE 2013u2 for Windows and VSE 2012u4 for Windows Phone (I couldn't find the newer one). Updated both to the newest version just to make sure. .NETCore v4.5.1 is still missing.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Then I installed VS for Windows (not desktop!) u3 and the folder appeared.

Comment: So I followed your way and install CS for Windows 2013 and the folder appeared.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the best way to solve this, but it worked for me:

1. Install "Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 (Offline Installer) for Windows Vista SP2, Windows 7 SP1, Windows 8, Windows Server 2008 SP2 Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 and Windows Server 2012" http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40779
2. copy
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1
   to
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5.1

Looking at the v4.5 dirs, the only difference between .NetFramework and .NetCore seems to be the .xml files and a couple extra dirs in .NetFramework. That is: .NetCore seems to be a subset of .NetFramework. So unless something was to explicitly copy "all" of .NetCore, this should work for most purposes.

Comment: I did what you stated above but have 1 problem: I cannot rename .NETFramework to .NETCore.. Any other ways for me to rename it?

Answer (score -1):

Seems that the missing framework is .net framework 4.5.1 and not .netcore 4.5.1. Since their is not .netcore 4 ..

Im addition to this would like to tell you that Windows 8 is told old and Vs 2013 is way old and you can replace it with Visual Studion Community Edition 2022 that is free